# Multiple integral Issue

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm given the following exercise:

$\iint\limits_D \exp(x^{2}+y^{2})dA$

And I dont even know where to start, any chance someone could give me a hint?

D is a half circle, given by:

$9\le x^{2}+y^{2}\le 16, y\ge 0$

Wheres A, I don't know what it is, its not given in the exercise. - Thats partly whats bugging me.

Comment: What are $D$ and $A$ supposed to be?

Comment: (on a bit of limb) how about starting with $dA=dxdy$ ?

Comment: What's $D$? If it's the unit disc you can use polar coordinates. Then you will get $$2\pi\int_0^1 r\cdot\mathrm{exp}(r^2)dr=\pi(\mathrm{exp}(1)-\mathrm{exp}(0))=\pi(e-1).$$

Comment: So you have half an annulus... try determining the solution for a general radius $r$, call it $I(r)$, and try computing $I(4)-I(3)$.

Comment: For $A$ ... could you try looking at the associated chapter(s) and see how it was previously used?

Comment: So you'll have me insert a value '$r$', instead of '$x^2+y^2$'?

Comment: Theres an A in the previous exercise about Characteristic polynomials, but that would be unrelated wouldn't it?

Comment: No... try checking the relevant sections on multiple integration.

Comment: Hmm... okay, $r$ was an unfortunate choice of variable, since you're using it for polar coordinates as well. You should visualize the thing as an integral over a disk. Let's call the radius of the disk $a$ instead... what you want is the difference of two integrals over two disks of different size.

Comment: Nothing; all I got is this:
$\newline$
Have $D$ draw a half circle, determinated by:
$\newline$
$9\le x^{2}+y^{2}\le 16, y\ge 0$
$\newline$
1) Draw the area, and describe it using polar coordinates $(r,\theta)$.
$\newline$
(I have done this)
$\newline$
2) Calculate the multiple integral:
$\newline$
$\iint\limits_D \exp(x^{2}+y^{2})dA$
$\newline$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The notation $\underset{D}{\displaystyle\iint }f(x,y)\;\mathrm{d}A$ has the same meaning as $\underset{D}{\displaystyle\iint  }f(x,y)\;\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$.

---

To evaluate an integral in a different coordinate system one has to find the absolute value of the [Jacobian determinant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) of the transformation. Using polar coordinates, we can transform the initial integral

$$\underset{D}{ \iint }e^{x^{2}+y^{2}}\;\mathrm{d}A=\underset{D}{\iint }e^{x^{2}+y^{2}}\;\mathrm{d}xdy$$

into this one

$$\int_{0}^{\pi }\left( \int_{3}^{4}e^{r^{2}}rdr\right) \mathrm{d}\theta ,$$

where the conversion factor $r$ is the Jacobian determinant (see Example 3 on the Wikipedia article), and observe that $r^{2}=x^{2}+y^{2}$:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\underset{D}{\iint }e^{x^{2}+y^{2}}\mathrm{d}A &=&\underset{D}{\iint }
e^{x^{2}+y^{2}}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y \\
&=&\int_{0}^{\pi }\left( \int_{3}^{4}e^{r^{2}}rdr\right) \mathrm{d}\theta  \\
&=&\int_{0}^{\pi }\left[ \frac{1}{2}e^{r^{2}}\right] _{3}^{4}\mathrm{d}\theta  \\
&=&\int_{0}^{\pi }\frac{1}{2}(e^{16}-e^{9})\mathrm{d}\theta  \\
&=&\frac{\pi }{2}(e^{16}-e^{9}).
\end{eqnarray*}$$

Answer (score 0):

The A in $dA$ refers to the infinitesimal thing you're integrating over. It just means that instead of a line, you integrate over a surface. A for Area.

As for a hint to start: Since you are dealing with circles, polar coordinates are a natural choice. I am sure these coordinates have been discussed in your lecture before. Note that $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$, where $r$ is the distance of the point from the coordinate origin. Also note that $dA = r dr d\phi$

Then, you can characterize the area $D$ by simple intervals for your polar coordinates: r will go from $3$ to $4$ and $\phi$ will go from $0$ to $\pi$.

Comment: Okay, I've gotten the 3 and 4, with $0$ to $\pi$ already, in the previous exercise. - and we've been around polarcoordinates yes, or a little. - its just extra homework I'm doing :) - I dont however get that; $dA = rdrd\theta$ part of what your saying.

Comment: Okay. $dA$ is what you get when each of the coordinates is changed infinitesimally. In cartesian coordinates, that is simply the rectangle $dx dy$. In polar coordinates, draw a line of radius r. Then add $dr$ to the radius and change the angle by $d\phi$. This gives a shape that isn't really rectangular, but for infinitesimal changes it doesn't matter. Now, one side of it has length $dr$, the other side has length $r d\phi$. Thus, the area of the shape is $r dr d\phi$.

Answer (score 0):

Some confusion is coming from not understanding what the $dA$ represents, so here's a link on [the area element in polar coordinates](http://keep2.sjfc.edu/faculty/kgreen/vector/Block3/jacob/node4.html) that hopefully will help clear up this point.